# printf x86 Assembly linking with GCC error

Tags: gcc, x86, printf, nasm

So I have been working with Assembly for a while now and I wanted to try using `printf` in assembly.

I looked up how to do it on multiple sites and the gist I got was something along the lines of this:

```
global main
extern printf

section .data
    msg db "Hello, World!", 0x0a, 0x00


section .text

_start:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push msg
    call printf
    mov eax, 0
    leave
    ret
```

I then assemble with NASM using:

```
nasm -f elf32 printing.asm -o printing.o
```

And link with GCC using:

```
gcc -m32 printing.o -o printing
```

And I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Operation not supported
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As far as I know the commands were right so how can I fix this error? I did look into it for a bit and found nothing relevant, the only conclusion I can think up is maybe I need to fix some references to `ld`?

Comment: Was that the *only* error message?  No earlier messages from the `gcc` command?  I'd expect "multiple definition of `_start`" because you defined your own but didn't use  `-nostartfiles`.

Comment: Just rename `_start` to `main`. Since you are calling `printf` you want gcc to initialize the C library.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I have done that (my mistake) now I get`/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Operation not supported`

Comment: Is that really the only line of output from your `gcc` command?  That seems very unlikely.  But if so, what OS and what GCC version / setup?  I don't think missing lib32 packages could explain that error.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 and the base GCC